# Angular 2 rc1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I m getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined error when i updated my app to rc1. Any idea what can cause that problem ?
Should i have used instead of '@angular/router-deprecated' ,'@angular/router' ?

```
 import {Component, provide, Optional, Inject, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
    import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
    import {CliRouteConfig} from './route-config';
    //import * as Redux from 'redux';

    import {RegisterSimple} from './register-simple/register-simple';
    import {Register} from './register/register';

    @Component({
      selector: 'account-app',
      providers: [],
      template: `
        <h2>Account</h2>
        <nav>
          <a [routerLink]="['RegisterSimple']" class="nav-register-simple">Register Simple</a>
          <a [routerLink]="['Register']" class="nav-register">Register</a>

        </nav>
        <hr>
        <div style="margin:20px; border:1px solid #ccc;">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
      `,
      directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RegisterSimple],
      pipes: []
    })

    @RouteConfig([

      { path: '/register-simple', name: 'RegisterSimple', component: RegisterSimple },
      { path: '/register', name: 'Register', component: Register },

    ].concat(CliRouteConfig))

    export class AccountApp {

      private userState: any = null;

      constructor(
        private ngZone: NgZone,
        @Optional() @Inject('UserStore') UserStore: any
      ) {
        let userData = {
          general: {
            userNodeID: 123,
            username: 'Max.m',
            firstname: 'Max',
            lastname: 'Mustermann',
            salutation: 'Mr',
            birthdate: '23.12.1988'
          },
          address: {
            street: 'Musterstraße',
            houseNumber: '4',
            postCode: '4020',
            city: 'Linz',
            countryCode: 'AT'
          },
          contact: {
            phone: '0123456789',
            email: 'max@mustermann.at',
            newsletter: true
          },
          payment: {
            accountHolderName: 'Max Mustermann',
            bic: 'AT65232323',
            iban: 'AT9837272727272'
          },
          culture: {
            currency: 'EUR',
            language: 'de',
            oddFormat: 'Decimal'
          }
        }

        this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {

          });
        });
      }
    }
```

Main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountApp, environment} from './app';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
bootstrap(AccountApp);
```

Error Message

```
EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0
browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78
browser_adapter.ts:78 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefinedBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78
browser_adapter.ts:78 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78
browser_adapter.ts:78 TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined
    at RouteRegistry.configFromComponent (route_registry.ts:112)
    at new RootRouter (router.ts:522)
    at routerFactory (router_providers_common.ts:31)
    at DebugAppView.get (AccountApp_Host.template.js:55)
    at DebugAppView._View_AccountApp_Host0.injectorGetInternal (AccountApp_Host.template.js:95)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.injectorGet (view.ts:145)
    at DebugAppView.injectorGet (view.ts:325)
    at ElementInjector.get (element_injector.ts:16)
    at DebugAppView._View_AccountApp0.createInternal (AccountApp.template.js:60)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (view.ts:110)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78
browser_adapter.ts:78 ERROR CONTEXT:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78
browser_adapter.ts:78 DebugContext
```

Comment: Does your `<body>` element contain a `<account-app></account-app>` tag?

Comment: Can you show us full error msg?

Comment: yes it contains.. On the page i can see the "Account" but the rest is missing...(nav tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error message. It was because I was trying to run most packages (common, core, etc) with rc.4 and still had the router at rc.1 (the latest version at posting). Moving the other packages back to rc.1 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like angular bug/version incompatibility. try running npm install, checking systemjs config, package.json, swapping router versions.